Could not find the `contentlibraryapi` module from Facebook
I am encountering an issue with importing a Python module named contentlibraryapi from Facebook Facebook events - Content Library and API. When I try to import the module using the statement
from contentlibraryapi import ContentLibraryAPIClient

I receive the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'contentlibraryapi'

I've tried installing the module using 
`pip install contentlibraryapi`, but I get another error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement contentlibraryapi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for contentlibraryapi


Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. **Verified PyPI**: Checked if the `contentlibraryapi` module is available on PyPI, but it seems it's not listed there.
    
4. **Modified Script**: Updated my script to include the path to the module:

```python
from contentlibraryapi import ContentLibraryAPIClient

# Create a client object if you have not already done so:
client = ContentLibraryAPIClient.get_instance(version='3') 

# Create a search object:
event_search = client.search_events(q="music")

# Function to display results from the search query:
def display_results(search_results):
    for event in search_results:
        print(f"Title: {event['title']}")
        print(f"Date: {event['date']}")
        print(f"Location: {event['location']}")
        print(f"Description: {event['description']}\n")

# No results are displayed until you provide display instructions:
results = event_search.query_next_page()

display_results(results)

Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to resolve the import issue. If contentlibraryapi is hosted on a private repository, I might need to install it directly from there, but I don't have the exact repository URL.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to properly install and import this custom/private module, or suggest alternative solutions to resolve the ModuleNotFoundError?


According to the Content Library FAQ and Product Terms, it is not allowed to export or download data outside the Meta-approved environment (i.e. the Jupyter workspace). Therefore, it is not possible to install and run the API client on your own Python environment.
